# conflict in use two jquery plugins in one page at asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

i used two jquery plugins in my page. one of them is a news tricker and its script is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(function () {
           $('#js-news').ticker();
       });
   });
</script>
```

and other is a jquery ui dialog for diaplay a dialog, and its script is:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function () {
    $("#divConsumerCartDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $("#aMpConsumerCartLink").click(function () {
        $("#divConsumerCartDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

when i am trying to run my page, this error occurred:

> microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method

each of they alone work properly, and together not work and occurred above error

please tell a solution for resolve my problem

thanks in advance

Comment: in witch line you get the error ?

Comment: in this line:  ... $("#divConsumerCartDialog").dialog({....

Comment: I've searched in the web.
many of the people tell haven't use some other javascript libraries at the same time. but i only use one library. but this problem not solved.

I understand who when i'm comments reference to ticker js file, then error not occured

Comment: could you possibly paste the links to the jquery plugin used for newsticker here? the dialog is jqueryui dialog right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/ as your newsticker, try this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#js-news').ticker();
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $("#divConsumerCartDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $("#aMpConsumerCartLink").click(function(evt) {
        $("#divConsumerCartDialog").dialog("open");
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/qJSKN/

On an unrelated side note, please don't write like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(function () {
           $('#js-news').ticker();
       });
   });
```

Because `$(function () {});` is a short hand for `$(document).ready(function () {});`.
By writing like this you are invoking DOMReady inside DOMReady.

Comment: thanks naveen. but i use two user controls in my project. as one user control include newstricker and other user control include dialog. and  my jquery functions as script are separately in themselves user control. and your approach not work for me

Comment: too, i put both jquery scripts in one file in my page who is include two user control, and again this not worked for me. and i understand problem is in one of the two js files for newstricker with "jqueryTricker.min.js" name. and when i comment this file reference, page and dialog work fine and newstricker not work

Answer (score 1):

Give the jQuery library an alias so there is no collision between javascript libraries (jQuery and microsoft jscript)

At the end of you jquery-1.4.2.min.js (for example), put

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then adjust your jQuery specific calls to use $j instead of just a $.  This should clear up your problem.

ex:

```
        $j(document).ready(function(){
               ......
```

Comment: thanks. i'm use jquery-1.6.2.js, and end of file is like this: `
    // Expose jQuery to the global object
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);` . at the end of `})(window);` ? or before or other place? i test both, but problem not solved.